# how much electrolyte is usually used on a regular 100 amp lead acid battery

Tags: battery, starter

I want to replace my 100 amp hour lead acid battery electrolyte, but i'm not sure the amount required.

I want to make it right the first time.

So if someone could please tell me how much apprx electrolyte  required for the common 100 amp hour 12v lead acid starter battery.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? Usually adding some distilled water is enough if the level is somewhat low. You just add into the each port until the battery plates are fully covered.

Comment: I agree with @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing but fill it up to the bottom of the split ring where the hole is (bottom of the hole where you access the cell). This ensures the plates remain covered under different conditions.